# Fortran compilation error

Tags: fortran

Dear Experts I am trying to use fortran on ubuntu 22. I am getting compilation error

```
yasir@yasir-X270:~/Downloads/bremge_orig$ gfortran bremge.F brebldt.F  -L  ./cern/2005/lib   -lkernlib -lmathlib -o main main.F

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lkernlib: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmathlib: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

But I already have these libraries in this folder:

```
yasir@yasir-X270:~/Downloads/bremge_orig$ ls
brebldt.F   brempa1.inc   libmathlib.a    main.F   rnpssn.o
brebldt.F~  fort.7        libpacklib.a    main.F~
bremge.F    libkernlib.a  libpdflib804.a  readme
```

If possible Please suggest some solution

Comment: Ubuntu 22?   So this is a Ubuntu Core 22 installation?  Not a 22.04 or 22.10 system?

Comment: If the libraries are in the *current* directory, perhaps you need `-L ./` in place of or in addition to `-L ./cern/2005/lib` ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to link against `./libkernlib.a ./libmathlib.a` instead of `-lkernlib -lmathlib`, as the shared libraries `libkernlib.so` and `libmathlib.so` do not seem to be present.